# "Send Mail As" Not Populating Primary Inbox with New Emails

Tags: gmail, pop3

Posting here because google help forums won't let me post my own thread, due to a #554 permissions error when I try to submit a new post and #555 permissions error when I try to reply to an existing one (have tried multiple google accounts and even VPNs, but tbh it's not really the issue I care about troubleshooting further).

I'm having an issue with the send mail as feature in gmail. I have my send mail as emails (aka secondary emails) added under my primary email, all treated as an alias, and I have verified and confirmed the secondary addresses via the regular process. My intent is to use my primary inbox as the nexus for all emails, without having to log into other accounts. However, I am experiencing some unexpected behavior.

Here's a couple scenarios and my observations:

1. Send email from my primary inbox using the secondary email address:

   - Works as expected, email goes through fine
2. Send email from my primary inbox (using either secondary or primary) to the secondary email address:

   - Email populates in primary inbox, does not populate in secondary inbox
3. Send email from external email address to secondary email address:

   - Email populates in secondary inbox, does not populate in primary inbox
4. Send email from primary inbox (using secondary email address) to external email address:

   - Email is received by external address, however, any reply from the external address does not route to primary inbox

The functionality is inconsistent based on the address it comes from, and does not appear to be working correctly. I am assuming by setting my email up as send mail as, I do not also need to set up a Check Other Mail using POP3, but if that is the workaround (or for whatever reason the way this is supposed to be set up), I can tolerate that. It would just appear unnecessary to me, given how the treat as alias is described.

If there is a better way to set this up, please let me know.